# Why didn't the other dragons come back the first time the spell was cast?

Tags: disney, raya-and-the-last-dragon

In Raya and the Last Dragon

> When the dragon gem spell was cast the second time, the dragons came back from the Drune.

Why didn't this happen the first time the spell was cast?

Comment: Probably because of plot convenience. These issues exist in so many different movies etc, and it's because they need a way to do [x] by doing [y], even if [y] had already been done and produced a different result.

Comment: Dragons are hard of hearing.

Answer (score 4):

Dragons desire unity (the opposite of Drunn that desire discord), and sacrificed themselves to help the humans - they however splintered into tribes, demonstrating the ingrained distrust in the human society.

The second time the humans and the last dragon worked together, this greater level of unity brought everyone back.

> “I don’t know why they chose me,” Sisu says, “it could have been any of us. All I know is they trusted me, and I trusted them. When they put their faith in me, it empowered me beyond anything I can imagine.”
>
> https://www.denofgeek.com/movies/raya-and-the-last-dragon-ending-explained/

The theme of the movie is that we are all the same inside and to really achieve anything we need to recognize our shared humanity and unite.

> CHAN: It’s absolutely mutual. It shows how when we’re young, as children, we don’t inherently hate each other. It’s something that’s learned. It’s something that comes through, whether it’s from a parental or family influence, or from your particular tribe. Those things are learned. That’s something to take from the movie. Those things can be learned, but they can be unlearned, as well.
>
> https://collider.com/raya-and-the-last-dragon-cast-interview/

In the end Sisu thanks Raya for trusting others. He would have been best placed to know what it would take to bring the dragons back.

> "The dragons are all brought back to life as they revive Sisu who thanks Raya for trusting others. Everyone returns to their significant others as Raya returns home to be reunited with Benga. She introduces him to Sisu as all the tribes come together peacefully to celebrate."
>
> <sub>[IMDb, *Raya and the Last Dragon*, Synopsis](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5109280/plotsummary?ref_=tt_stry_pl#synopsis)</sub>

As Sisu said:

> “Maybe it's broken because you don't trust anyone. But sometimes, you just have to take the first step.”

Comment: Thanks. I will dig around to find some supporting evidence.

Comment: It's a great theory, but it really needs evidence.

Comment: Bounty Awarded.